# Swapping with rvalues

Tags: c++, swap, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

Suppose I want `swap` that works on rvalues, and don't want to write 4 versions for all combinations of rvalue/lvalue references (rvalue/rvalue version is kinda pointless but it doesn't hurt). I came up with this:

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_same_no_ref
    : std::is_same<
        typename std::remove_reference<A>::type,
        typename std::remove_reference<B>::type
    >
{};

template <typename A, typename B,
    typename = typename std::enable_if<is_same_no_ref<A, B>::value>::type
>
inline void my_swap(A&& a, B&& b) {
    typename std::remove_reference<A>::type t = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(t);
}
```

which seems to work as expected. Is this okay? Or am I missing something important that will make me suffer later?

Comment: Why not just: `template <typename A, typename B> void swap(A&& a, B&& b) { auto t = move(a); a = move(b); b = move(t); }` ?

Comment: @MM. this is less symmetric. I do realize that it will only work if `A` and `B` are 'mutually movable' anyway, but still.

Comment: I believe you meant `is_same_no_ref` instead of `std::is_same_no_ref`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While I see no inherent concept flaw in your implementation, I would make three suggestions.

(**note:** I'll refer here to an implementation of the concept of *swaping rvalues* as `swap_rvalues`)

---

### Exclude const types from the template deduction

- **How?**

Assuming

```
template <typename A, typename B>
struct is_same_no_ref
    : std::is_same<
        typename std::remove_reference<A>::type,
        typename std::remove_reference<B>::type
    >
{};
```

change the *enable condition* from `std::enable_if<std::is_same_no_ref<A, B>::value>` into the following.

```
std::enable_if<
    std::is_same_no_ref<A, B>::value &&
    !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<A>::type>::value &&
    !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<B>::type>::value
>
```

- **Why?**

Without excluding const types from the template deduction, passing const variables to `swap_rvalues`, as in the following,

```
int const a = 0, b = 0;
swap_rvalues(a, b);
```

induces the compiler to flag errors regarding internal implementation details, what is not very user-friendly.

---

### Move the *enable condition* to the return type declaration

- **How?**

Instead of

```
template<typename A, typename B, typename = typename std::enable_if<...>::type>
inline void swap_rvalues(A&& a, B&& b);
```

declare it like the following

```
template<typename A, typename B>
inline typename std::enable_if<...>::type swap_rvalues(A&& a, B&& b);
```

- **Why?**

Even though *highly* improbable, the explicit definition of the third template parameter of `swap_rvalues` is possible, effectively overriding the *enable condition*. This may allow code to compile which shouldn't and nastiness could follow. This is completely avoided using the return type declaration for the *enable condition*.

Consider the following example.

```
template <
        typename A, 
        typename B, 
        typename = typename std::enable_if<
            is_same_no_ref<A, B>::value &&
            !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<A>::type>::value &&
            !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<B>::type>::value
        >::type>
inline void
swap(A&& a, B&& b) {
    typename std::remove_reference<A>::type t = std::move(a);
    a = std::move(b);
    b = std::move(t);
}

struct B;
struct A{A(){} A(B const&){}};
struct B{B(){} B(A const&){}};
swap<A, B, void>(A(), B());
```

It compiles, even though it clearly shouldn't! `A` and `B` are not even related, they just happen to be constructable given a reference of the other.

---

### Reuse code [aka [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle)]

- **How?**

Since the rvalues are already *given a name*, simply forward call [`std::swap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/swap), instead of providing a brand new implementation of `swap_rvalues`.

- **Why?**

Why [reinventing the wheel](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reinventing_the_wheel)†? `std::swap` already provides the intended behavior once rvalues *are given a name*, so why not reusing it?

---

### Conclusion

The final implementation of `swap_rvalues`‡ would look like follows.

```
template <typename A, typename B>
inline typename std::enable_if<
    is_same_no_ref<A, B>::value &&
    !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<A>::type>::value &&
    !std::is_const<typename std::remove_reference<B>::type>::value
>::type
swap_rvalues(A&& a, B&& b) {
    std::swap(a, b);
}
```

---

**Footnotes**

<sub>† *"To **reinvent the wheel** is to duplicate a basic method that has already previously been created or optimized by others."*</sub>

<sub>‡ `swap_rvalues` in fact would better be called `swap` in a real scenario.</sub>