# How many overloads should there be for a visitor that takes a copyable and movable class?

Tags: c++

I have a class `Foo` that is copyable and movable. It can accept and store any of a number of primitive numeric types. Clients are expected to retrieve this data via the `TypedFoo<T>` interface to `Foo`, where `T` is a numeric type. When clients write code that is meant to work for any of a number of types, they are encouraged to call functions, published as part of the interface, that call client-defined visitors, then internally dispatch on types. This eliminates the need for clients to put and maintain large switch statements in their own code. For instance, the library could make this API available:

```
template<typename V>
auto apply_foo_visitor(const Foo& f, V visitor) -> decltype(visitor.template apply<int16_t>(f))
```

and the user could write this code to determine the size of an individual element in a Foo called `myFoo` without knowing what numeric type the instance contains:

```
class GetSizeVisitor {
public:
    GetSizeVisitor() {}
    template<typename T>
    size_t apply(const mda::TypedFoo<T> & foo) {
        return sizeof(T);
    }
};

// main code
size_t elementSize = apply_foo_visitor(myFoo, GetSizeVisitor());
```

Within the library, I could write overloaded versions of a visitor that take a class

- by value:
  `template<typename V>
  auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo f, V visitor)`
- as a const lvalue ref (as in the example above):
  `template<typename V>
  auto apply_foo_visitor(const Foo & f, V visitor)`
- as a nonconst lvalue ref:
  `template<typename V>
  auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo & f, V visitor)`
- as an rvalue ref:
  `template<typename V>
  auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo && f, V visitor)`

My question is which of these I should provide. I want to give users as much freedom as possible to write their visitors in such a way that they can enforce constness on a Foo if they want, or allow it to be modified if they don't, and I also want them to copy it if they want, or move it if they don't. However, I don't want to write redundant or unnecessary code in my implementation, and I want to make sure that the compiler will be able to handle any reasonable usage of the visitor functions that the client might come up with.

Are there any best practices in this regard? For instance, is it enough for me to write one version of the visitor that takes an lvalue ref and another that takes an rvalue ref, without qualifying either as const, and leave it at that?

Answers to the following two questions:

[Preventing non-const lvalues from resolving to rvalue reference instead of const lvalue reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7748104/preventing-non-const-lvalues-from-resolving-to-rvalue-reference-instead-of-const)

[Swapping with rvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18942438/swapping-with-rvalues)

suggest that it's best in the scenarios described by the questions to write a version that takes an rvalue ref, and that this will be general-purpose enough to handle lvalues correctly. Is that going to be true in my case as well, where I want to move only when it's appropriate, and otherwise access via a const or non-const reference?

Comment: Are the visitors called via template or via a virtual function?

Comment: @aschepler, via template, not via a virtual function. I updated the question to clarify that.

Comment: And do you need to enforce things like "if the `Foo` object is accessed via `const`, the visitors may not modify it"? Or is there just one interface to any sort of `Foo`?

Comment: @aschepler, as I wrote, "I want to give users as much freedom as possible to write their visitors in such a way that they can enforce constness on a Foo if they want, or allow it to be modified if they don't, and I also want them to copy it if they want, or move it if they don't."

Comment: I've been trying to write an answer, but I'm still not clear on the side of the code that uses a `Foo` and calls the library function which will eventually call these visitors. Can you add an example showing how you'd like that to look?

Comment: @aschepler, I modified the question to show that.

Comment: For flexibility, can you make one overload with a template parameter (with a Foo default type), and make the parameter a [universal reference](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (rvalue of a template parameter)? This seems to be the case that behavior was designed for, where you don't want to have to make separate overloads for every kind of reference.

Answer (score 1):

So looking at your potential `apply_foo_visitor` signatures:

```
template<typename V> auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo f, V visitor);         // #1
template<typename V> auto apply_foo_visitor(const Foo & f, V visitor); // #2
template<typename V> auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo & f, V visitor);       // #3
template<typename V> auto apply_foo_visitor(Foo && f, V visitor);      // #4
```

If a user wants to be able to change the original `Foo` object, only #3 or #4 will work. (I assume copying a `Foo` has value semantics, not reference semantics.) If a user passes an lvalue `Foo` expression like a variable name, #4 will not work. If a user passes an rvalue `Foo` expression like a call to a function returning `Foo` by value, #3 will not work. If a user passes an lvalue `const Foo` expression, neither #3 or #4 will work. Both #1 and #2 will always work, but passing an lvalue to #1 will always make a copy, which could be unnecessary if the visitor just wants read-only access to the value and will not copy or move that value elsewhere.

So I'd recommend the three reference overloads #2, #3, and #4. To avoid too much repetition, put as much logic as possible elsewhere. I don't know how you create your `TypedFoo` interface objects, but supposing that `Foo` has:

```
class Foo
{
    // ...
private:
    template <typename T> TypedFoo<T> typed_iface() const;
    // ...
};
```

then an implementation might look something like this (not tested):

```
namespace detail
{
    template <typename Tuple, typename Enable = void>
    struct common_or_void
    { using type = void; };

    template <typename ... Ts>
    struct common_or_void<std::tuple<Ts...>,
                          std::void_t<std::common_type_t<Ts...>>>
    { using type = std::common_type_t<Ts...>; };

    template <typename ... Ts>
    using common_or_void_t = typename common_or_void<std::tuple<Ts...>>::type;
}

class Foo
{
    // ...
private:
    template <typename T> TypedFoo<T> typed_iface() const;

    template <typename T>
    const TypedFoo<T>& transfer_cref(TypedFoo<T>& iface) const &
    { return iface; }
    template <typename T>
    TypedFoo<T>& transfer_cref(TypedFoo<T>& iface) &
    { return iface; }
    template <typename T>
    TypedFoo<T>&& transfer_cref(TypedFoo<T>& iface) &&
    { return std::move(iface); }

    // F could be Foo, Foo&, const Foo&
    template <typename T, typename F, typename V>
    static decltype(auto) apply_as_type(F && foo, V && visitor)
    {
        TypedFoo<T> iface(foo);
        return std::forward<V>(visitor).apply(
            std::forward<F>(foo).transfer_cref(iface));
    }

    template <typename F, typename V, typename ... IntTypes>
    using apply_ret_type = detail::common_or_void_t<decltype(
        apply_as_type<IntTypes>(std::declval<F>(), std::declval<V>()))...>;

public:
    struct FreeFuncImpl // Easier than friend-ing three templates.
    {
        template <typename F, typename V>
        static auto apply_foo_visitor(F && foo, V && visitor)
            -> apply_ret_type<F, V, std::int8_t, std::uint8_t /* ... */>
        {
            if (type_is<std::int8_t>())
                return apply_as_type<std::int8_t>(
                    std::forward<F>(foo), std::forward<V>(visitor));
            else if (type_is<std::uint8_t>())
                return apply_as_type<std::uint8_t>(
                    std::forward<F>(foo), std::forward<V>(visitor));
            /* ... */
        }
    }
};                    

template<typename V>
decltype(auto) apply_foo_visitor(const Foo & f, V && visitor)
{
    return Foo::FreeFuncImpl::apply_foo_visitor(f, std::forward<V>(visitor));
}
template<typename V>
decltype(auto) apply_foo_visitor(Foo & f, V && visitor)
{
    return Foo::FreeFuncImpl::apply_foo_visitor(f, std::forward<V>(visitor));
}
template<typename V>
decltype(auto) apply_foo_visitor(Foo && f, V && visitor)
{
    return Foo::FreeFuncImpl::apply_foo_visitor(std::move(f), std::forward<V>(visitor));
}
```